# Firebase function in firebase function

Tags: swift, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database, data-synchronization

The following function has to return all of my users's friends list. However it only does it for one of the friends. I know this is because the 2 firebase functions are running async, however I am not sure what I have to change the function so that it runs the way is should. That is retrieve all friends.

```
///retrieves all of user's friends
    func fetchFriends(completion: @escaping ([FriendModel])->()){
        FRIEND_REQ_REF.child(CURRENT_USER_ID).observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in
            var friends = [FriendModel]()
            if snapshot.value as? Int == 0 {
                self.USERS_REF.child(snapshot.key).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snap) in
                    if let dictionary = snap.value as? [String : AnyObject]{
                        let friend = FriendModel()
                        friend.setValue(dictionary["userName"], forKey: "userName")
                        friend.setValue(dictionary["name"], forKey: "name")
                        friends.append(friend)
                        completion(friends)
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
```

this is my data structure:

```
FRIEND_REQ_REF
              firebaseUserID
                 friendFirebasegivenID : 0
                 anotherFriendFirebasegivenID : 0
USERS_REF
            friendFirebasegivenID
                 userName : String 
                 name : String 
            anotherFriendFirebasegivenID : 0
                 userName : String 
                 name : String
```

Comment: I think by using observeSingleEvent you are not pulling data from server but from local cache.  Try using observe or look into keepSynced.

Comment: that is actually not the problem. that part works fine. what this function is doing is it's pulling all the friends of a user from the FRIENDS_REQ_REF, then based on their username is pulling their snapshot values from. The problem is in the beginning where it has to pull all the users, it's only doing one. I think I need something like a for loop for all snapshot values, but there is no such thing so I am not sure how to approach this problem

Comment: I misread your code.  Once you pull FRIEND_REQ_REF all data below should be pulled also.  There is no need to pull from firebase again. Delete the code and just do print(snapshot.value) to see structure.  It should be a dictionary of everything.

Comment: actually it will not pull all the data once I pull the friend_req_ref. I need the second part too. See, what I am doing is find the friends of the current user from one node, then look for their information in another node, called the urers_ref node. I think I should also make a digram of my data structure, I will edit that

Comment: can you print(snapshot.value) and post that?  I need to see the structure that is being returned

Comment: snapshot.value = Optional(0)
snapshot.value = Optional(0)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162367/discussion-between-rmickeyd-and-dre-84w934).

Comment: there are 2 friends with vaule 0, which I want, but the function only retrieves one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
///retrieves all of user's friends
    func fetchFriends(completion: @escaping ([FriendModel])->()){
        FRIEND_REQ_REF.child(CURRENT_USER_ID).observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
            var friends = [FriendModel]()

            if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
                for (_,k) in dict.enumerated() {

                    if k.value == 0 {

                        self.USERS_REF.child(k.key).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snap) in
                    if let dictionary = snap.value as? [String : AnyObject]{
                        let friend = FriendModel()
                        friend.setValue(dictionary["userName"], forKey: "userName")
                        friend.setValue(dictionary["name"], forKey: "name")
                        friends.append(friend)
                        completion(friends)
                    }
                })
                    }


                }
            }

        })
    }
```